# Are Bosspy and Copy10 fake/scam apps?

Tags: applications

I want to install it on my daughters phone to monitor her activity. 
I've tried researching it myself and I see a lot of reviews and posts in several forums saying they are legit apps, but I suspect they are all fake posters.

Was hoping someone here could provide some insight, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find much *real* info/review about those apps. Some reviews say that they are fake, but one thing I can conclude is, **both apps are not available on Google Play Store**. As far as I can see, both apps provide their installer on their websites only (links are not provided to prevent spam, since it's easy to find them). As a user who often installs 3rd-party app from unknown source, **I'd say to be very careful with these kinds of app, as they could be malicious, even though they are from their "official sites"**.

If you really need parental control apps on Android, it'd be better to try some that are already reviewed:

- [tom's GUIDE - 10 Best Parental Control Apps](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/pictures-story/596-6-best-parental-control-apps.html)
- [your sphere - 10 Android Parental Control Apps](http://internet-safety.yoursphere.com/2014/04/10-android-parental-control-apps/).

All of these apps have been reviewed, and they are on Google Play Store, which is "more" secured. (Not saying that all apps on Play Store are safe, but it tends to, since Google did remove malicious apps on there)

Conclusion: in the end, it's up to you to believe which is which. If you can trust the developers, then you might just use it.

**Disclaimer**: I'm not affiliated to the blog/article and all of the apps at all.